# MVVM and DevExpress

Tags: mvvm-light

I am using the devexpress control suite in my  project. One of there controls, the tab control, requires that I load the control not the viewmodel into the tabs. What would be the best way to do this and still seperate the information correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Dan, I don't know where you got the information that DXTabControl from DevExpress cannot be used in the MVVM manner. Please take a look at the following code/XAML.

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication91 {
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl {
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel {
        public ViewModel() {
            Employees = new List<Person> {
                new Person { FirstName = "Larry", LastName = "Ellison" },
                new Person { FirstName = "Steve", LastName = "Jobs" },
                new Person { FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Gates" }
            };
        }

        public List<Person> Employees { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Person {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <core:DXTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
        <core:DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </core:DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplate>
        <core:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding LastName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </core:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </core:DXTabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Oh it works. but in when using a VM in items source it doesn't remember the state. So each time it opens a tab or goes to a previous tab it has to re-render. This is confirmed with DevEx.

Comment: Don't really undertand what you mean by re-rendering, but does standard TabControl work better in this situation?

Comment: No they both have the same issue. Binding to a collection that is not controls doesn't work correctly. If you add the control to the tab collection it works fine.